# How to restrict user input from 0 to 99 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to achieve user input restriction, I really tried hard but didn't find any solution to fix this issue. Could someone please help me how to restrict user to enter value from 0 to 99

Thanks

```
<input type="number" placeholder="Enter value" onChange={(e)=>this.handleValue(e.target.value)}/>

handleValue = value=> {
   Math.min(100, Math.max(99, value))
}
```

Comment: Math.min / Math.max simply return the smallest/largest value of the arguments.

Answer (score 2):

HTML5 to the rescue:

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="99">
```

> - elements automatically invalidate any entry
>   that isn't a number (or empty, unless required is specified).
> - You can
>   use the required attribute to make an empty entry invalid. (In other
>   words, the input must be filled in.)
> - You can use the step attribute
>   to constrain valid values to a certain set of steps (e.g., multiples
>   of 10).
> - You can use the min and max attributes to constrain valid
>   values to lower and upper bounds.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number)

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <label for="myNumber">Pick a number between 0 and 99:</label>
    <input id="myNumber" type="number" name="myNumber" min="0" max="99" required>
    <span class="validity"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This doesn't stop the user entering a number out of bounds nor prevent them from submitting a form without _some_ javascript. A complete answer should probably demo or at least point to the [Constraint Validation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation#the_constraint_validation_api).

Comment: @Emissary [an invalid input will not allow the form to be submitted](https://jsbin.com/tifejul/1/edit?html,js,console,output). Enter a number out of bounds and see if the submission works. (JS added just to stop the form going away).

Comment: @VLAZ Oh, my mistake! Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

If the desire is to prevent input that is above or below, you will want to prevent the event from firing.

```js
const handleValue = (event) => {
  const value = event.target.value;
  if (value > 99 || value < 0) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return;
  }
}

<input type="number" placeholder="Enter value" onChange={handleValue}/>
```